# Error '424' Object required in if statement

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

The code is expected to run a loop and delete all the respective rows of cells that are in column b and have no cell value. On running the code, Error '424' Object Required is displayed. why do this error normally arise as I get this error a lot in if statements?

```
Sub cleaning()

Dim s As Worksheet
Dim r As Range
Set s = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set r = s.Range("B:B")

r.Activate



For Each c In r
If c.Value Is Nothing Then
s.Range("B" & c.Row).EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next c


End Sub
```

Comment: C value can't be nothing, c can, c value can be null

Comment: I changed it to c.value is null and run the loop. Same error message.

Comment: If you Dim c (and you should) what would you Dim it as? Cell? Then try For Each c in r.Cells

Comment: There is no variable type as cell. The closest is cellformat.

    For Each c In r.Cells
    If c.Value Is Null Then
    s.Range("B" & c.Row).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    Next c


still the same error

Comment: You want "If c.Value = Null" not if "If c.Value Is Null".  You could also use "If c Is Nothing"  Note that this may cause problems when you delete the row (which is referenced in the comments in the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Try this out:

```
Sub cleaning()
Dim s As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Integer
Set s = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
lastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

For c = lastRow To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(c, 2).Value = "" Then
        s.Range("B" & c).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: You will want to loop backwards.  `For c = lastrow To 1 step -1` or it will not get the time that there are two blanks in a row.

Comment: You're right, of course! Slipped my mind, will edit accordingly.

Comment: Thank you guys it did work. thank you very much. Now the questions. why you run the loop from the bottom and what was the main error in my code?

Comment: My best suggestion is that you should debug your code and put a break point on every line so you can see what it does. This would be a good example to do that with because it's small.